# General Good Practice Using Bootstrap panel class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So I have been using Bootstrap's panel class for a few months now and I can not determine if what I have been doing with the panel class is good or not. So I used to use the panel class like so

```
  <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-heading">

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would wrap the panel classes inside a col-md-12.
 I have also found that the following works:

```
  <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="row">

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-heading">

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">

                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is pretty much which method is better as far as for responsive design. They both appear to be responsive. Is it necessary to wrap the panel panel-default and all its contents in a div with a column class or is that being handled already by the outer div with the row class?

Comment: I don't know which is better but I use the first.  Though if I were to use only one column class it would be `col-xs-12`

Comment: @Dan, ok that's what I was thinking too, col-xs-12 would make more sense. Thanks for the tip

Comment: For responsive design no matter if you will use the `col-xs-12` (12 -100%) or will not use. The only difference is that `col-` classes add some padding (don't remeber properly but I think it's 15px). You can see the difference in the following [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LtTTn/).

Comment: @Nicolai, I see, its still responsive it just adds padding to the left and right, cool thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bootstrap 3 **[code examples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels)**, the `panel` element does not need to be wrapped in `col-**-*` wrappers and wrapping it in `col-md-12` makes no sense because by default the panel takes `100%` of the `container` width.

However, it is acceptable to wrap it in the `col-**-**` class if you want it to take a width not of 100%, but `33%`.

**[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/T1pB4oQw45)**